# "An active access token must be used" (Dec 2012) && The proper way to set up Facebooks PHP-SDK for Ajax calls to get the user-id

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

This is giving me quite some headache. I have an page-tab-application, where DB-interaction uses the facebook-user-id to assign and save data and also to check user permissions. Until a weak ago everything was working fine, but now with the upcoming december-changes this setup doesnt work anymore:

**config.php:**

```
$facebook = new Facebook( array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));
```

**index.php:**
includes config.php and gets the signed request (not important for the question

**javascript.js:**
calls the read-user-status.php and handles the data

**read-user-status.php:**
gives json-response, includes config.php and calls the $facebook -> getUser()-function to get the uid

Even when called from the index.php directly after page-load, I sometimes get the uid and sometimes I don't. Strangly enough I usually have to wait a little until I reload the page and then it works again. But this isn't always the case. This all is just very strange to me.

**EDIT:** Should have mentioned that this call:

```
$uid = $facebook -> getUser();
if ($uid) {
    try {
       // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
       $user_profile = $facebook -> api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       error_log($e);
       $uid = FALSE;
     echo "EXCEPTION $e";
   }
}
```

gives out "EXCEPTION An active access token must be used to query information about the current user".

I know there quite a lot of similar questions out there, but none of the answers were helpful to my particular (and probably to the new breaking changes relied) problem.

**EDIT2:** I now suppose that it is a sdk-bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238039849657148 , thanks to CBroe). Any recommendations for a work-around are of course very welcome.

**EDIT 3, TEMPORARY SOLUTION**
Everytime you make an ajax request, you post the token you get from the FB.getLoginStatus or FB.login and read it out in the php file and set it via $facebook -> setAccessToken. Not suitable in all circumstances (you definately need to use post), is slower and brings some security issues, but still works.

Comment: do your permissions include offline access ?

Comment: Sounds like you are affected by the bug I reported beginning of November, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238039849657148 They’ve confirmed it and say they’re working on a fix – but since the change is only a few days away now, they should hurry up a little …

Comment: @CBroe: Thank you I had a feeling, that it might be bug, as it shows such a strange and irregular behaviour, but didn't find this bug-page.

Comment: @Hemc: no I disabled it, as it will be depricated in a few days anyway. But even with it enabled and the breaking changes enabled, it todesnt work (it works with the breaking changes disabled though).

Comment: @CBroe: If you post this as an answer, I would give you credit for this, otherwise I will give it to my own :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you are affected by the bug I reported beginning of November, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238039849657148

They’ve confirmed it and say they’re working on a fix – but since the change is only a few days away now, they should hurry up a little …

Comment: Update: They fixed this – updating to the newest version of the PHP SDK (v.3.2.2) should solve this issue (I did for me).

Comment: No, latest update does not solve anything. It seems to work randomly

Comment: Still getting this issue, however workaround as per first comment on FB link (ie save token into a session var) seemed to do the trick.

Comment: This bug is still happening in some random cases

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by doing the following...

```
if(!$user){

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email',
                'redirect_uri' => $app_url
                ));
    header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
}
```

**I also added my app to be integrated with:**

- Website with Facebook login
- App on Facebook
- Page Tab

Comment: Havent tried this as the app is already out, but its nice to have so many viable answers for this question.

Answer (score 0):

try by adding access token to request.

```
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?access_token=' . $accessToken);
```

Comment: The accessToken behaves the same as the user-data-call. Sometimes it is send correctly, sometimes it is not. If it is once set and I save it to a session-variable, it works, but only for the duration of the session, afterwards it seems like it stopped working at all, until I deauthirze the app and authorize it again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around for this, until it is fixed (which it seems like, wont be in time until the changes take place).
Everytime you make an ajax request, you post the token you get from the FB.getLoginStatus or  FB.login and read it out in the php file and set it via $facebook -> setAccessToken. Not suitable in all circumstances (you definately need to use post), is slower and brings some security issues, but still works.

Answer (score 0):

if it you are lucky and your version of php sdk still registers session variables than right after _graph method declaration:

```
//find this method below
        protected function _graph ($path, $method = 'GET', $params = array ())
        {

//paste right after _graph method declaration code below:
            if (isset($_SESSION["fb_".$this->getAppId()."_access_token"]))
            {
                $this->setAccessToken($_SESSION["fb_".$this->getAppId()."_access_token"]);
            }
//till here
//and you are good to go
//remember: your version of sdk must be registering access token variable in session
//right after ajax call
//i used git to get version before last commit of sdk published on github
```