# Facebook 2 different applications with the same domain name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The option is called "App Domains" on the basic config menu of each app.

Can I use the same domain name (example.com) for 2 different facebook applications?

Is it permitted? Would I have any problems?

More info: I am using Facebook Login method on both of the applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a facebook bug from the latest breaking changes:

["An active access token must be used" (Dec 2012) && The proper way to set up Facebooks PHP-SDK for Ajax calls to get the user-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635991/an-active-access-token-must-be-used-dec-2012-the-proper-way-to-set-up-fac)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can.**

People who have purchased wildcard SSL certificates (`*.yourCoolDomain.com`) will always put the same domain there and simply use subdomains to host their different applications.

```
app1.yourCoolDomain.com
app2.yourCoolDomain.com
```

Comment: I am using SSL certificate for my domain but I implemented the separation with code. Not with subdomains. I am using the same example.com as domain setting to the developer s panel. I am experiencing strange things, like after refreshing the page, access_token disappears although there is a facebook cookie.

Comment: What do you mean by disappears? Is it no longer valid?

Comment: after refresh [access_token] => [expires] => 0
It is actually a close/open inline popup window but still.